# JavaFX 8 ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID on supposedly valid mp3 file

Tags: java, javafx-8, audio-player

I'm writing a media player in Java and it seems to work well except that for 2 songs it fails to load them. I've checked their encoding and they appear to be valid. They don't seem to have the wrong extension either. According to Oracle's documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) the file should load, but it doesn't. This is the exception error that `MediaPlayer.getError().printStackTrace()` gives me.

```
MediaException: UNKNOWN : [com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer@713c5088] ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID: ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.getMediaException(MediaException.java:160)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$_MediaErrorListener.onError(MediaPlayer.java:2660)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaPlayer$EventQueueThread.HandleErrorEvents(NativeMediaPlayer.java:685)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaPlayer$EventQueueThread.run(NativeMediaPlayer.java:419)
```

And here's what GSpot v2.70a tells me about the audio file.
[image]

EDIT: I was never able to figure out what was wrong with it, but Java 9 fixed the issue.